# How to show native validation error for specific input on change event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I have a classic HTML5 form. I would like using jquery/javscript to show the browser native error tooltip when the user change a specific input value. I would like to avoid the user try to submit the form to see all errors.

For that, I tried with the functions `checkValidity()` and `reportValidity()` but it works only if I add `alert('test');` in my condition...so weird

*JS script*

```
myInputJqueryObject.on('change', function() {
   if ( !this.checkValidity() ) {
       this.setCustomValidity( 'Custom error !!!' );
       var $form = $('#my-form');
       if( $form[0].checkValidity() === false) {
           $form[0].reportValidity();
           //alert('test'); <-- works only if I active this line code
           return true;
       }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to check the form validity when you know that the input is invalid. You can omit `if( $form[0].checkValidity() === false)`. Also you can `reportValidity` on the input itself.
And `setCustomValidity` takes some time to be applied to the input field. So you have to wrap `reportValidity` into `setTimeout`:

```js
$('input').on('change', function() {
  var self = this;
  if (!self.checkValidity()) {
    self.setCustomValidity('Custom error !!!');
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.reportValidity();
      self.setCustomValidity('');
    }, 1);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form"><input value="del me" required></form>
```

Comment: In your example, there is only one problem. When you clean the input, the error message is displayed correctly, but if your write text again, the error message is displayed again.

Comment: *self.checkValidity()* is always *false*

Answer (score 1):

Based on 'Kosh Very' answer, I found the solution. It sounds good without bugs.

*JS Script :*

```
 $('input').on('focusout', function() {
   var self = this;
   var validity = self.checkValidity();
   if( !validity ){
      if( self.validity.patternMismatch ){ //<-- Optionnal : Condition to keep others native message errors except Pattern. 
          self.setCustomValidity( 'Custom Error about pattern!!!' );
      }
      setTimeout(function() {
            self.reportValidity();
            self.setCustomValidity( '' ); //<-- Important to reinit
      }, 1);
   }
 });
```

Comment: +1 for your effort! But your solution works only if `validity.patternMismatch` is true. In some cases it may be wrong.

Comment: I tested 1) when I clean the input, the message error about 'required' is displayed. 2) when I insert a wrong pattern, my custom message works. 3) when I insert a right pattern, no message error anymore.

Comment: In my example, I want to customize the message only for `patternMismatch` and keep native message errors for others cases and that sounds good.

Comment: Your problem displayed in the question was `why it does not work without alert`. Nothing about pattern validation and other specific conditions. Anyway, it's great that it works as you want!

Comment: Ah ok. I understand now why you said that. Thank you !